# MySQL Workbench bug, users and privileges page is missing

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Anybody know how to fix this without having to reinstall the app? The users and privileges page every time that I click on it:

[image: description]

This happens every time I click on the users and privileges page, fullscreen, windowed, it doesn't seem to make a difference. I can add a user and the buttons at the bottom respond as if the page was working normally, but nothing shows up on the page.

Using version 8.0.21.

If I don't have to reinstall everything that'd be great.

Comment: try to update to version 8.0.22

Comment: Check the log of the application (Help -> Show Log File). Is there any error logged?